# iOS 10.2 + Safari + Client Certificates crashes Safari

Tags: safari, ios, certificate

Yesterday I updated my iPhone 6S to iOS 10.2, and now I cannot access web sites requiring client certificates. Safari prompts me for the client certificate to use but then immediately crashes. I tried with my iPad running iOS 10.0.1 and it works just fine. On my Mac / PC it works with any browser whatsoever.

Can someone else confirm this problem?

Comment: I'm beginning to think this has something to do with https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204132 . Even though my iPhone says the cert is verified...

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This clearly has something to do with StartSSL / WoSign (client) certificates.

Even though there is no error and Safari just crashes, everything works when I try self signed client certs or client certs from another root CA.

Very weird ...

Answer (score 0):

This is why:

https://support.apple.com/es-us/HT204132

I've tried adding as root certificate the CA, but still not working. Maybe I miss something.

Hope it helps someway.

Comment: Please change link to English. I think it is a simple “es-us” —> “en-us”